# How to make a dynamic variable inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have an object list below like this:

```
tmp_pp{
 q_p1_cost: "20",
 q_p1_margin" "10",
 q_p2_cost: "100",
 q_p2_margin: "5",
}
```

... and so on

I want to make a loop which and loop all dynamic key starts from 1, so that in the v-for it whille show all value based on what I command below:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-1" v-for="(pp, i) in tmp_pp" :key="i">
  <div>
     <strong>{{ i + 1 }} </strong>
  </div>
  <div>
      <strong>{{ `pp.q_p$(i)_cost` }}</strong>
 </div>

  <div>
      <strong>{{ pp.q_p[i]_margin }}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two approach I do, the first one is `pp.q_p$(i)_cost` . Since I want `$(i)` switch to 1, I make like this, but not shown.
The second approach I do is `pp.q_p[i]_margin`. The [i] is the index value I want ot make for a loop but not any thing shown yet.

What is the problem with my for loop, how can I able to make the v-for dynamic key successfully? Any help would be appricated.

Comment: Your data doesn't look like valid JSON. Please either explain or show us some *real* data.

Comment: This is object not json

Comment: Please explain as that isn't very clear. A JavaScript object *is* represented by JSON.

Comment: Ah, so you've edited your code and show that it is in fact JSON. Better to post it this way from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

Your data object is not valid.

I guess you need something like this

```
[
  {
    cost: 'q_p1_cost',
    margin: 'q_p1_margin'
  },
  {
    cost: 'q_p2_cost',
    margin: 'q_p2_margin'
  }
]
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue 

const q_data  =
[
  {
    cost: 'q_p1_cost',
    margin: 'q_p1_margin'
  },
  {
    cost: 'q_p2_cost',
    margin: 'q_p2_margin'
  }
]

const App = {
  setup() {
    const tmp_pp = ref(q_data);    
    return { tmp_pp }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-1" v-for="(pp, i) in tmp_pp" :key="i">
  <div>
     <strong>{{ i + 1 }} </strong>
  </div>
  <div>
      <strong>{{ pp.cost }}</strong>
 </div>

  <div>
      <strong>{{ pp.margin }}</strong>
  </div>
<div></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```